# Find the remainder of the division

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Find the remainder when $f(x)=x^{2017}-1$ is divided by $(x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)$

I have expanded the function and factorized it. The remainder I had found was $-x^3-2x^2-3$ 
I am not sure if I was right ! So can anyone tell me the other way to solve it ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{2017}-1=x((x^3)^{672}-1)+x-1\equiv x-1\pmod{x^3-1}\equiv x-1\pmod{x^2+x+1}$$

and $$x^{2017}-1=x((x^4)^{504}-1)+x-1\equiv x-1\pmod{x^4-1}\equiv x-1\pmod{x^2+1}$$

Luckily both remainders are same and $$(x^2+x+1,x^2+1)=1$$

Comment: I finally found my mistake! Thank you so much.!

Answer (score 2):

The hint:
$$f(x)=x^{2017}-x+x-1$$ and
$$x^{2016}-1=(x^4)^{504}-1$$ is divisible by $x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1).$

Also, $$x^{2016}-1=(x^3)^{672}-1$$ is divisible by $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1),$
which gives that there is polynomial $g$ for which
$$f(x)=(x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)g(x)+x-1.$$

Comment: Thank you ! I finally found my mistake:) !

Comment: @November ft Blue You are welcome!